# Is there a proof-of-work scheme vulnerable to length extension attack?

Tags: proof-of-work, length-extension

I wonder is there an example of proof of work scheme that uses a hash function and requires the hash function to be immune to length extension attack? I mean the scheme, that becomes easy to solve if we use vulnerable hash function, but has strong security properties as soon as the underlying hash function resists length extension.

Comment: **What research have you done?** I'm asking because sharing research efforts helps everyone! Tell us what research you did, what you found, and why it didn’t meet your needs. That shows users you took time trying to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and (most important) it helps you to get more relevant on-point answers. In case of doubt, you can start by searching this site for related Q&As that might shed light on your question. At worst it will help you frame [*“a better question”*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); at best it might even answer it.